# PHP variable in a HTML string created from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to use some simple AJAX and then passing my variable through a HTML string.

Struggling to get some PHP included to print the value into the string.  Been trying like this and the variable prints blank even though there is a value assigned to $user_id.

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?user=<?php $user_id ?>&q="+str,true);
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this or better solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `echo`:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?user=<?php echo $user_id; ?>&q="+str,true)
```